# Laravel wherebetween doesn't accept negative numbers

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, laravel, laravel-4

Is there anyway to find a range of negative numbers in a database with laravel?  The above statement doesn't execute my query properly.  It keeps returning null.

```
  $userprofile = $userprofile->whereBetween('unix_birthyears', array(-100,-50))->get();
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's a bracket missing in your code. Browsing at [Laravel-4 Advanced Wheres](http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres) shouldn't there be a **get()** at the end of the call chain?

Comment: Edited it.  In my code I do have the get() at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if your DB field is not int, the query values will be treated as a string and the opposite, so maybe this is something to test.

You can try:

```
->where(DB::raw('`unix_birthyears` BETWEEN -100 AND -50'),true)->get();
```

Comment: My DB field was var so changing it to int worked thanks.  However, I'm storing unix timestamps which will run over 11 digits.  I switched my db field to BigInt.  Is this best practice? thanks again

Comment: If you are going to have datetime comparisons, it should be a timestamp ofcourse but for general numeric comparisons, yes int / bigint etc depending on the range size you will need available.

Comment: @alou is there any eloqouenty way of that?